# Can I change the interval of a periodic Handler while running?

Tags: android, timer, handler

I have this perodic **Handler**:

```
int interval = 35000;

Runnable runnableForConsumption = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.postDelayed(runnableForConsumption, interval);
            new ConnectWSTask().execute();
        }
    };

    void startRepeatingTask() {
        runnableForConsumption.run();

        }

    void stopRepeatingTask() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnableForConsumption);
    }
```

And I want for the first run an interval of 2000ms and after this run I want an interval of 35000ms.

Is it possible to change the interval of this handler during running?

Or is there any other possibility to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
    public void run(){

        handler.postDelayed(runnableForConsumption, interval);

        if(interval == 2000){
            interval = 3500;
        }
        new ConnectWSTask().execute();
    }
```

The point is you change `interval` to 3500 before your second `postDelayed`

Comment: i think this not will work. the run method will be executed once when i call `runnableForConsumption.run();` and once the interval is setted in postdelayed it will be always executed in this interval. Or do I think in the false way?

Comment: oh ok. It really work. Didnt thougt that. But it's working the other way round. the if clause behing the postdelayed.

Comment: Edit my answer. when you first call `runnableForConsumption.run()`, the `interval` is 2000, in the `run` method, the interval is set to 3500 followed by a `postDelayed`. Then your second `run` will be scheduled at `currentTime+3500`. And all subsequent `run` will use the same delay time